# Defining program as beta

Tags: c#, .net

I want users to test my program's beta builds. There's a simple checkbox in the options screen to check for beta updates. However what would be the best way to define a build as beta? Would that be to check if the build version of the assembly information is not zero (so 1.0.0.1, 1.0.0.239 are beta and 1.0.1.0 is final), it'll be defined as beta? Or is it better to have a variable (boolean) called `IsBeta`? Or any other way?

Please share your thoughts about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using **[Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/)**.

Answer (score 1):

I think a boolean/prop file setting is a better choice.  It is very black and white.  Trying to deduce beta or not-beta from the version number might be clear now, but at some point you'll either increment incorrectly, or want to have exact control (turn off beta for this specific release) and have to hack your numbering scheme.

This will also help when you release 1.0.0.239 (set as beta=true), and 10 minutes later change "small dog" to "puppy", but don't really want to push another update to your users. So 1.0.0.240 would just be beta=false. I mention this without knowing how many builds you do or how you control the users access to the builds...